# Find numbers in a string and wrap span around each number

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a text which is a table of contents:

```
004 Foreword
007 Introduction
008 Chapter 1
012 Chapter 2
130 Chapter 3
274 Chapter 4
…
```

What I need, is to find the page numbers and then wrap each number in a `span`:

```
<span class="page-number">004</span> Foreword
<span class="page-number">007</span> Introduction
<span class="page-number">008</span> Chapter 1
<span class="page-number">012</span> Chapter 2
<span class="page-number">130</span> Chapter 3
<span class="page-number">274</span> Chapter 4
…
```

The numbers could contain of 1 to 3 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a table of content, I assume that the number you are looking for is the first number of the line.

```
$re = '~^\D*\K\d{1,3}~m'; 

$subst = '<span class="page-number">$0</span>'; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

details:

`^` means the start of the line, since the m modifier is used

`\D` any character that is not a digit

`\K` removes all that have been matched by the left of the pattern from the match result

Comment: if i want to viceversa, mean, i want to wrap except the first word in a string, how will i do that??

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
<?
    $text = <<<TEXT
004 Foreword
007 Introduction
008 Chapter 1
012 Chapter 2
130 Chapter 3
274 Chapter 4
TEXT;

    echo preg_replace('/^(\d+)/m', '<span class="page-number">$1</span>', $text);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code test [here](https://eval.in/177703)**

```
<?php

$text = 'TEXT
004 Foreword
007 Introduction
008 Chapter 1
012 Chapter 2
130 Chapter 3
274 Chapter 4
';

$text = preg_replace('/[\d]{3}/m', '<span class="page-number">$0</span>', $text);
echo $text;
```